# move occurs because `data` has type `Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Tags: rust

I am trying to print some data for debugging purposes when I encountered an error. You can have a look at the [full code here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#mlx53xipih8brmo2tysei5).

The error occurred when I tried to print data returned from the `prepare_hash_data()` function, which returns a `Vec<u8>`.

```rust
let data = self.prepare_hash_data()?;      // returns Vec<u8>
println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data)?);  // error here
let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
hasher.input(&data[..]);
println!("{}", hasher.result_str().as_str());
self.hash = hasher.result_str();
```

The `prepare_hash_data()` function is given below. Other details are omitted. Simply, it is just a function that returns `Vec<u8>`

```rust
fn prepare_hash_data(&self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, failure::Error> {
        let content = (
            self.hash_prev_block.clone(),
            self.transactions.clone(),
            self.timestamp,
            DIFFICULTY,
            self.nonce
        );
        let bytes = bincode::serialize(&content)?;
        Ok(bytes)
    }
```

The error given is

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `data`
  --> src/block.rs:63:23
   |
60 |         let data = self.prepare_hash_data()?;
   |             ---- move occurs because `data` has type `Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
61 |         println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data)?);
   |                                          ---- value moved here
62 |         let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
63 |         hasher.input(&data[..]);
   |                       ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

#### I tried the following ways

- Implementing `Copy` trait. But, `Vec<u8>` can't have the `Copy` trait as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215753/how-do-i-implement-copy-and-clone-for-a-type-that-contains-a-string-or-any-type).
- Looking at [E0382](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0382.html) given in the error message, there are two ways suggested.

  - Using a `reference`, we can let another function borrow the value without changing its ownership.

    - But how should I use `reference` in this example?
    - Should I change the function signature to something like this `fn prepare_hash_data(&self) -> Result<&Vec<u8>, failure::Error>`?
  - With `Rc`, a value cannot be owned by more than one variable.

    - Don't know how to implement.
- I tried cloning the data by `println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data.clone())?);`

  - But, it gives another error `backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized`
  - For the full error log, click [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#ge3y48vgz4igwva1lmmdqk)

What should be the correct approach to printing some data that can't be `copied` or `cloned` without `moving` it for later usage in subsequent lines?

I did look at the following solutions but can't relate the answer.

- [move occurs because value has type Vec, which does not implement the `Copy` trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398106/move-occurs-because-value-has-type-vect-which-does-not-implement-the-copy-t)
- ['move occurs because value has type' Rust error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129106/move-occurs-because-value-has-type-rust-error)

Comment: I am trying to print `Vec<u8>`, similar to the string. Full code is available [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#mlx53xipih8brmo2tysei5). And full error log for #3 [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#ge3y48vgz4igwva1lmmdqk). Updated question as well.

Comment: Note that this question is flawed; what you probably actually try to do is to convert the `Vec<u8>` to a hex string and then print this one. Maybe look here: https://programming-idioms.org/idiom/175/bytes-to-hex-string/2635/rust

Comment: Closing as "needs clarity" because that detail makes most of my answer irrelevant. This is the prime example of an XY problem.

Comment: Details are given for the sole purpose of giving clarity. Just printing `Vec<u8>` was not the goal, rather it's usage in any function that `moves` data. Rephrasing the question **What should be the correct approach to printing some data that can't be copied or cloned without moving it for later usage in subsequent lines?** And the data can be `non-utf8`.  Does a different approach to an answer make a question flawed?  And details were added later upon request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to print some data for debugging purposes

The code you provided:

```rust
println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data)?);
```

Is not the correct way to debug-print data.

For one, `String::from_utf8` **consumes** the data, destroying it in the process. Further, your data most likely isn't valid UTF8 data, so `String::from_utf8` will only throw an error.

Use debug printing instead, it works out of the box:

```rust
println!("{:?}", data);
```

---

I retract my previous answer because it partially missed your problem.

It still contained valuable information, so I have kept it below.

**--Previous Answer--**

Your problem is that `String::from_utf8` **consumes** its argument, meaning, `data` cannot be accessed any more afterwards.

Here is your problem in a more compact example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u8> = "Hello!".as_bytes().to_vec();

    // Consumes `data`
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data).unwrap());

    // `data` cannot be accessed any more, as it got moved
    // into `String::from_utf8`
    println!("Length of vector: {}", data.len());
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `data`
 --> src/main.rs:9:38
  |
2 |     let data: Vec<u8> = "Hello!".as_bytes().to_vec();
  |         ---- move occurs because `data` has type `Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
5 |     println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data).unwrap());
  |                                      ---- value moved here
...
9 |     println!("Length of vector: {}", data.len());
  |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
  |
help: consider cloning the value if the performance cost is acceptable
  |
5 |     println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data.clone()).unwrap());
  |                                          ++++++++
```

In your case this can be easily fixed, though. The reason it consumes the data is because `String` is an **owning** variable. It owns its data, meaning, if you create it from a `Vec`, it stores the `Vec` data internally.

There is another type: `&str`, a string slice. It's very similar to `String`, just that it doesn't own its data, but merely references it. That means you can create it without destroying `data`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u8> = "Hello!".as_bytes().to_vec();

    // Borrows `data`
    println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&data).unwrap());

    // `data` is still accessible because it was only borrowed
    println!("Length of vector: {}", data.len());
}
```

```
Hello!
Length of vector: 6
```

---

That said, the given solution is only a workaround. The **proper** way to fix this is to implement `Display`.

As your `data` object clearly has more meaning than just a bunch of bytes, create a proper struct that represents its meaning.

There are two ways I would consider:

- A newtype struct, like `struct MyData(Vec<u8>)`, for which you can implement `Display`.
- A `String`. As you convert it to a string anyway, why not just make it a string right away, as the return value of `prepare_hash_data`? Note that **if** your reason to have it a `Vec` is that it is **binary** data, then you shouldn't convert it to a string via `from_utf8`, as it's not UTF-8 data. If it is valid UTF-8 data, however, use a `String` right away, not a `Vec<u8>`. And `String` already implements `Display` and can be printed without further conversion.

Comment: The third case hints that the data are _not_ valid UTF-8, in fact, since OP gets a `FromUtf8Error`. Therefore, they can't use `String` (or `&str`) at all.

Comment: @Cerberus OP probably meant to convert to a hex string, which something else than `from_utf8`.

Comment: @Cerberus Where did you see the `FromUtf8Error`?

Comment: Got directions from this answer to solve this issue by writing a helper function that takes reference of `Vec<u8>` and doesn't own it ensuring later usage.

Comment: `@Cerberus Where did you see the FromUtf8Error? ` Added [error log](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#ge3y48vgz4igwva1lmmdqk) later to the question that got generated when tried using `println!("{}", String::from_utf8(data.clone())?)`.

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy Don't use `&Vec<u8>`, use `&[u8]` instead, it's 100% compatible and more general

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer as it clarified lots of concepts related to the question which is valuable. Now, as per your suggestion to `Don't use &Vec<u8>, use &[u8]`, why it is better as both references are `borrowed type` though one point to `owned Vec<u8>` and another to `borrowed [u8]`? Where `&Vec<u8>` falls short in terms of compatibility?

Comment: Is this the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function) for your suggestion?

Comment: `&Vec<u8>` is not owned; `Vec<u8>` is. `&Vec<u8>` is a reference to an owned vector, and so is `&[u8]`. You can pass `&Vec<u8>` into a function that expects `&[u8]`. All the extra functionality that a `Vec` reference brings isn't available if it isn't `&mut`; so you don't gain any extra functionality from it. To the cost that your function is then **only** compatible with vectors. For `&[u8]`, it accepts arguments of the types `&Vec<u8>`, `&[u8;10]` (references to arrays) or `&[u8]` directly. You gain generality at no drawback.

Comment: It's called the [robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) - if you pass data somewhere, do it as conservative as possible. If you receive data (as in an argument), do it as liberal as possible. And `&[u8]` accepts a strict superset of `&Vec<u8>`, so it is the better choice for a parameter, as it is more liberal.